# Label on UIButton appears corrupted

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

I have a very simple view controller with some `UIButton`s of type `UIRoundRectButton`. They look okay in Interface Builder but on the device / simulator the text label appears to be clipped in a strange way. Changing the size of the button does not affect the issue. Neither setting the text in code by calling `setTitle:ForControlState:` does. I attached two screenshots to visualize the issue.

Does anybody experienced this problem? Any ideas?

[image: InterfaceBuilder]
[image: Device / Simulator]

Comment: Can I have your code where you are making the buttons dynamically

Comment: Are you making the button entirely through IB?

Comment: I think you are using AutoLayout and copied buttons. Some of their constrains are messed up and incorrect. Most likely baseline or something like that. I don't rememmber from the top of my head.  You can disable autolayout or recreate buttons in IB.

Comment: I don't create the buttons in code. They are created in IB and connected there using the outlets of the ViewController. This worked till I tried to apply some images to the button - after that the buttons seem to be broken.

Comment: Try disabling AutoLayout and then enabling it again.

Comment: I copied and pasted the buttons indeed! I will have a look into this....

Comment: @ChristophHalang , try what suggested by Mindaugas. Moreover, as your last comment, are you sure you have removed the images correctly? Look inside the left inspector to see if there are other UIImage somewhere

Comment: Disabled AutoLayout -> Everything fine again. Thank you all! Do we (I?)need to add an answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Fogmeister and Mindaugas: Disabling and Enabling Autolayout for the superview of the buttons solved this issue.